# Jenkins PHP Sample Test Project

Tags: php, jenkins, integration-testing

Running ubuntu and followed the directions from here: http://edorian.posterous.com/setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects

But when I save the configuration I get 500 Error:

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM

Any ideas? Jenkins git plugin is installed.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Status Code: 500

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from {"":["hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser","7"],"authorOrCommitter":false,"branches":{"name":"**"},"browser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.dry.DryPublisher","url":"http://dev.evanta.com/gitweb/?p=mydemo.git"},"buildChooser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN"},"clean":false,"disableSubmodules":false,"excludedRegions":"","excludedUsers":"","gitConfigEmail":"","gitConfigName":"","gitTool":"Default","ignoreNotifyCommit":false,"includedRegions":"","localBranch":"","pruneBranches":false,"recursiveSubmodules":false,"reference":"","relativeTargetDir":"","remotePoll":false,"scmName":"","skipTag":false,"userRemoteConfigs":{"name":"","refspec":"","url":"file:///home/mirey/mydemo"},"value":"1","wipeOutWorkspace":false}
Stacktrace:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from {"":["hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser","7"],"authorOrCommitter":false,"branches":{"name":"**"},"browser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.dry.DryPublisher","url":"http://dev.evanta.com/gitweb/?p=mydemo.git"},"buildChooser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN"},"clean":false,"disableSubmodules":false,"excludedRegions":"","excludedUsers":"","gitConfigEmail":"","gitConfigName":"","gitTool":"Default","ignoreNotifyCommit":false,"includedRegions":"","localBranch":"","pruneBranches":false,"recursiveSubmodules":false,"reference":"","relativeTargetDir":"","remotePoll":false,"scmName":"","skipTag":false,"userRemoteConfigs":{"name":"","refspec":"","url":"file:///home/mirey/mydemo"},"value":"1","wipeOutWorkspace":false}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:616)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:488)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:162)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from {"":["hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser","7"],"authorOrCommitter":false,"branches":{"name":"**"},"browser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.dry.DryPublisher","url":"http://dev.evanta.com/gitweb/?p=mydemo.git"},"buildChooser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN"},"clean":false,"disableSubmodules":false,"excludedRegions":"","excludedUsers":"","gitConfigEmail":"","gitConfigName":"","gitTool":"Default","ignoreNotifyCommit":false,"includedRegions":"","localBranch":"","pruneBranches":false,"recursiveSubmodules":false,"reference":"","relativeTargetDir":"","remotePoll":false,"scmName":"","skipTag":false,"userRemoteConfigs":{"name":"","refspec":"","url":"file:///home/mirey/mydemo"},"value":"1","wipeOutWorkspace":false}
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:575)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(GitSCM.java:1508)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(GitSCM.java:1438)
    at hudson.scm.SCMS.parseSCM(SCMS.java:63)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.submit(AbstractProject.java:1790)
    at hudson.model.Project.submit(Project.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:990)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:699)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:574)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM from {"":["hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser","7"],"authorOrCommitter":false,"branches":{"name":"**"},"browser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.dry.DryPublisher","url":"http://dev.evanta.com/gitweb/?p=mydemo.git"},"buildChooser":{"stapler-class":"hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN"},"clean":false,"disableSubmodules":false,"excludedRegions":"","excludedUsers":"","gitConfigEmail":"","gitConfigName":"","gitTool":"Default","ignoreNotifyCommit":false,"includedRegions":"","localBranch":"","pruneBranches":false,"recursiveSubmodules":false,"reference":"","relativeTargetDir":"","remotePoll":false,"scmName":"","skipTag":false,"userRemoteConfigs":{"name":"","refspec":"","url":"file:///home/mirey/mydemo"},"value":"1","wipeOutWorkspace":false}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:633)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:377)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:373)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:566)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the buildChooser parameter of the constructor public hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM(java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.util.List,hudson.plugins.git.UserMergeOptions,java.lang.Boolean,java.util.Collection,boolean,boolean,hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildChooser,hudson.plugins.git.browser.GitRepositoryBrowser,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,boolean)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:627)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildChooser from {"stapler-class":"hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN"}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:633)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:377)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:625)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified type class hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN is not assignable to the expected class hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildChooser
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:603)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: Maybe try using a git:// URL instead of http:// ? Ref: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9312

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion However, I am not using github. I wanted to get the simplest test running first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Jenkins instance to check this on at the moment, but this line in the stacktrace caught my eye:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified type class hudson.scm.browsers.FishEyeSVN is not assignable to the expected class hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildChooser

Did you configure a code browser such as FishEye for your job?  If so, does it work if you remove that?

Comment: Yes, this caught my eye as well. I did not choose Fisheye, nor I am sure how to remove it.

Comment: You should be able to edit the XML configuration file for the job, and ask Jenkins to reload it from the "Manage Jenkins" page.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I was running the task on a (Windows) slave. The slave instance had not been started as an administrator, so it couldn't run administrator-level commands.

After logging into the slave as administrator and restarting the instance, the error seemed to be solved.